# InDesign not applying footnote separator formatting

Tags: adobe-indesign, formatting, footnotes

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't being applied? I want a full point and an emspace after the footnote number before the footnote text, which is what I've told it to do but all it's doing is putting a normal space in.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs if your footnotes for some reason has been manually edited (or perhaps imported from a Word document). The link to the footnote formatting is broken and the footnotes no longer reflect the changes you make.

A solution can be:

- Enter *Type > Document Footnote Options*.
- Set *Footnote Formatting > Separator* to a single space (like it is currently).
- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to leave the text field.
- Set *Footnote Formatting > Separator* to whatever you want.

This way you should be able to reset the formatting and gain automatic control again.

[image]

If this fails you can try to use *Type > Convert Footnotes and Endnotes* to first convert the footnotes to endnotes and then convert them back to footnotes.

(Btw: I don't think you want that "\" in your separator. The "." doesn't need to be escaped, it's not a GREP selector.)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, Wolff!

Comment: Glad to help! If the solution worked for you please consider accepting the answer.